# Add more fields to auth User model and then use it for authentication in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-auth-models

I want to add more fields to auth User model and then use it for registration,login and logout . For example i need an image field to store profile picture and an interger/date field to store date of birth . I having hard time understanding the custom authentication . I want to register normal user using html template and then login .

Comment: The Django documentation has an *extending the user model* section that explains the strategies to store extra data related to the user: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

Comment: Ok so i made new employee model with onetoone field now which model should i call to save() new user **User** or **employee** ?